# NHibernate and Memcached - should use_minimal_puts be enabled?

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, caching, memcached, second-level-cache

I use NHibernate with Memcached as a second level cache and have always been curious about the `cache.use_minimal_puts` configuration option.

According to the documentation:

> hibernate.cache.use_minimal_puts: Optimizes second-level cache operation to minimize writes, at the cost
>   of more frequent reads. This setting is most useful for clustered
>   caches and, in Hibernate3, is enabled by default for clustered cache
>   implementations.

To be clear, I'm not running Memcached in a cluster environment, but it does run on a remote machine. Another factor to consider may be whether or not there is any major difference in speed between reading and writing to Memcached.

Would I benefit from enabling `cache.use_minimal_puts` in this scenario?

Comment: "at the cost of more frequent reads" - Reads also implies in overhead over network, right?

Comment: @PlínioPantaleão - Good point..so perhaps a better question would be: are writes (a lot) more expensive than reads in memcached?

Comment: I don't have any evidence to support my opinion, but I don't believe this. This is only true in distributed enviroments because an write could cause you to lose caches on other machines. If this had been true in single machine case I think they would have done it before :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don’t have experience in NHibernate but have worked with Second level caches in Hibernate and I have been told that the same concepts are applicable to both.

The basic idea behind providing the parameter **hibernate.cache.use_
minimal_puts** is that before hibernate puts an object in cache it first check the second level cache whether the object is already present there, and if not then only put there.

This would be helpful **ONLY** when the data reads from caches are very less expensive than data updates. This is what the docs means about the following

> ...optimization of second-level cache operation to minimize writes, at
>   the cost of more frequent reads.

The case that fits perfectly for this kind of optimization is replication in clustering.

If you are using clustering then the put operation is very expensive as it activates cache replication listeners in case of clustered caches. If you are not using clustering then this put operation is comparatively very cheap.

Even in case of clustering there might be cache providers which rely on invalidation of entities instead of replicating the changes done to them. In that case too, this parameter would be useless.

One factor that can hamper performance is the kind of replication synchronous or asynchronous) used by Memcache. I have not used MemCache but EhCache supports both models.

So in your case as you are **NOT** using clustering and though the cache is on a remote process I seriously doubt that there would be any performance benefit by setting this parameter to true.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add few more details.

`hibernate.cache.use_minimal_puts`, setting this value to `true` will prevent it from blindly overwriting the previously cached values, which solves clustered cache problems. according to the manual, it is enabled by default for clustered cache implementations.

`Hibernate` provides the configuration property `hibernate.cache.use_minimal_puts`, which optimizes cache access for clustered caches by increasing cache reads and decreasing cache updates.

`CacheMode.REFRESH` will bypass `hibernate.cache.use_minimal_puts` effect